# Plus sign removed from string passed as a parameter to a stateful widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm passing an email with "+" in it using this

```
 static String getVerify(String email) => "$verify?email=$email";
  GetPage(
    name: verify,
    page: () {
      final String email = Get.parameters['email']!;
      return VerifyPage(email: email);
    },
    transition: Transition.fadeIn),
```

but on the verify page  that plus is gone

[image: You can see that the email is being passed correctly to the route but on the verify page the plus sign is missing and I get a space]

You can see that the email is being passed correctly to the route but on the verify page the plus sign is missing and I get a space
[image: verify page]

Comment: I don't see much code about how you throwing your data to another screen and can't give you a proper answer. BUT I see that you are using > Get.parameters and maybe it can be a problem. Maybe some in-built regex are cutting your email string. Also, have you tried with a string "++++++++++" or other special signs?

Comment: I bet you're passing "+" in a URL, which is another way of saying %20, which means a URI-encoded space character (hex 20).  You should stop using string concatenation to make URLs, and use the proper Uri constructor instead, which properly escapes such characters.

Comment: thanks @RandalSchwartz fixed it by replacing the + in the string with this `email.replaceAll('+', '%2b')` before passing to new screen

Comment: Which would have been solved if you had used Uri.replace to construct your URLs like I said previously, and you wouldn't need to "specialcase" the plus.  Do you know all the other chars you have to specialcase? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by replacing the plus sign with this
email.replaceAll('+', '%2b')
before passing to the new page